# Day-Light Sensing LED Light

Tags: led, light-sensor

I am looking for an example of a day-light sensing LED light, similar to https://www.evilmadscientist.com/2007/a-simple-and-cheap-dark-detecting-led-circuit/ but instead of turning on when dark, I want it to turn on when light. Could anyone point me to an example, or lead me down the right path?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE - in general, don't make people click through links. Draw the circuit using the built in circuit editor and have it in the question :)

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll be sure to do that in future posts!

Comment: He's suggesting you do it in this one. Your question becomes useless to anyone else when that link dies.

Comment: What you are looking for is called an ambient light sensor, e.g. OPT3001 www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opt3001.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You have two simple possibilities:

1. Switch the position of the resistor and the phototransistor. This way the resistor will pull down the base of the NPN when it's dark and the phototransistor will pull it up when it detects light.
2. Use a PNP instead of the NPN transistor and keep the resistor and the phototransistor where they are.

Comment: Great, thanks for the quick response! I'll give this a try.